# Can't install curses package in pycharm [ Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement curses-win(from versions: none)]

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, package, curses

when i try to install curses-win package i head ERROR

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement curses-win (from versions: none)

Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter

command output:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement curses-win (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for curses-win

i've installed numpy and tensorflow clearly

Comment: There is no such thing as `curses-win`: https://pypi.org/project/curses-win/ returns error 404. What are you trying to install? Do you mean https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses or https://pypi.org/project/windows-curses/ ?

Comment: i want to download curses

Comment: What do you mean by this: "Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter"
_What command_ are you running at the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

I faced with this problem when I tried to install `cantools` using `pip` on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I solved this issue by installing the `pytest-runner` package previously:

```
$ pip install pytest-runner --user
```